# On Page Change Listener

Tags: android, webview

I have an app that has four activities and it is possible to navigate between these activities by a button

The first activity has a `Webview` wish browsing `www.facebook.com`, if you go to another activity, when you come back to this activity the `Webview` will be back at the main page `facebook.com` even though I already browsed to `facebook.com/messages` or another place in facebook.

I want that `webview save it` change so if I scroll down or open any link, when I go back from another activity it will stay the same place I leave it.

This is my code:

**java class**

```
public class Kik extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kik);



    String url = "http://m.facebook.com/";
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView4);

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



    ImageButton imgbt1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonfk);
    ImageButton imgbt2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtontk);
    ImageButton imgbt3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonik);
    ImageButton imgbt4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonkk);
    ImageButton imgbt5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonyk);

    imgbt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent a = new Intent(Kik.this,Main.class);
        startActivity(a);   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    imgbt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent b = new Intent(Kik.this,ss.class);
        startActivity(b);   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Rerer this one http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/

Comment: it dose not work still if i go to another activity and come back to the webview it will reopen the facebook.com not the place i was in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to save instance state.

I hope this tutorial can help:

[Saving (and Retrieving) Android Instance State – Part 1](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/)

[Saving (and Retrieving) Android Instance State – Part 2](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-2/)

**EDIT:**

```
public String [] tab1url;
private static final String TAB1 = "url";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        tab1url = savedInstanceState.getStringArray(TAB1);
    }
 }

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArray(TAB1, tab1url);
}
```

Comment: for sorry as i understand he said this not working with the webview

Comment: Really? I didn't find "this is not working with webview" warning in both of links that I post here.

Comment: Allowed Bundle Value Types
boolean
boolean[ ]
Bundle (yes – store a Bundle in a Bundle)
byte
byte[ ]
char
char[ ]
CharSequence
CharSequence[ ]
ArrayList<CharSequence>
double
double[ ]
float
float[ ]
int
int [ ]
ArrayList<Integer>
long
long[ ]
Serializable
short
short[ ]
SparseArray